# Контент в <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть `frame`, который показывает видео с другого сайта, на этом `frame` нужно разместить `image` (он будет появляться на определенной секунде и через 3 секунды исчезать, если не кликнем по нему).

Когда происходит клик по нему выплывает `PopUp` и видео останавливается.

Использую `iframe` с bootstrap.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если у видео-вендора есть js api, то делается через него. Если же его нет, то это можно сделать через postMessage и DOM/html5 api.

Comment: вендера js api нет. можете пожалуйста по подробней расказать о методе postMessage.
вот кстати ссылка на видео
http://crazysob.bekey.io/osemrecipe/videodemo/video/onion.mp4

Comment: Про postmessage тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage но вы должны иметь доступ к этому сайту. Самый простой способ для вас думаю будет выкачать это видео и разместить у себя на сайте в теге <video>

Comment: Спасибо. После проделанных манипуляций  отпишусь)

Answer (score 0):

Ставишь два блока друг на друга(frame и изображение).
Задаёшь изображению `opacity` > чем видео и  `visibility: hidden;`.
Дальше скрипт

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
$(.photo).css("visibility", "visible");
 }, `определённая секунда`);


setTimeout(function(){ 
$(.photo).css("visibility", "hidden");
 }, `определённая секунда + 3`);
```

Чтоб остановить видео надо повесить `click` на само видео. Продолжить воспроизведение тем же методом

Comment: таким способом видео в фрейме не остановится. Из-за политики безопасности вы не можете эмулировать события в фрейме, вне одного домена.

Comment: Остановку можно сделать просто повесив клик на `video`

Comment: повесить событие на видео в фреме с другого сайта можно только через postMessage, если у этого сайта нет своего js api для управления и если вы можете редактировать js на том сайте. по другому не сработает.

Comment: @x3zone согласен. Не знал

Comment: @x3zone прошу прощение за неверный ответ. Протестил и реально не работает)